# how can i copy string to another variable and output with if else statement

Tags: c, if-statement, c-strings

```
    #include<stdio.h> 
    #include<string.h>

    int main(void) 

    {    

        //Assigning string to name1//
        char name1[8] = "Aaeric";

        //will be used to copy name1 to copyname//
        char copyname[8];  

        //Assigning string to name2//
        char name2[7] = "Mudus";

         //prompt for input//
             int i;
                 printf("Choose 1 or 0: ");
                     scanf("%i \n", &i);

    }



    //for copying string of name1 to copyname//
        if (i = 0)
        {
            strcpy(copyname, name1);
            puts(copyname);
            return 0; 
        }
        else
            puts(name2);
     }
```

> I want to copy the string to another variable and output with if-else condition through this way only but I am getting error.

> The output is the expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘if’

Comment: You cannot see that the `main` function ends with the `}` in the middle of the code? The code needs to be inside a function.

Comment: your if statement is not inside the main function. Also if(i==0) not i=0. If statement brackets are not matching

Comment: Hi kaylum. Thanks for the help. I did as you said but i think my if statement is not running. Output is still Mudus even if i entered 0 as input. Also my terminal is prompting two time for a input.

Comment: Hi kaylum. Thanks for the help. I did as you said but i think my if statement is not running. Output is still Mudus even if i entered 0 as input. Also my terminal is prompting two time for a input.

Comment: `scanf("%i \n", &i);` --> look here

Comment: @sergeyrar Thank you for your help. I am new to stack and C. My program is now running fine. Only one issue i am facing. My terminal is prompting for input two times.

Comment: don' edit you question this way. Know the answer makes no sense. This should be a comment.

Comment: @mike what should i do now. should i edit question or delete question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char name1[8] = "Aaeric";

  //will be used to copy name1 to copyname//
  char copyname[8];

  char name2[7] = "Mudus";

  int i;
  printf("Choose 1 or 0: ");
  scanf("%i", &i);

  if (i == 0)   // <<<<< use == instead of =
  {
    strcpy(copyname, name1);
    puts(copyname);
    return 0;
  }
  else
   puts(name2);
}
```

- poinless comments removed
- code snippets moved into `main`
- code formatted properly
- `scanf("%i \n", &i);` replaced with `scanf("%i", &i);`
- `if (i = 0)` replaced with `if (i == 0)`